# Stuck on Logic Gates C program. (New to C)

Tags: c, logic

Thanks for helping me out, here's a section on my code.

```
printf("Thank you, now please enter the logic gate");
scanf("%s", &C);

if (C == 'AND')
{
    if (A == 1 && B == 1)
    {
        (A && B == 1);
        printf("You have chosen the AND logic gate \n");
        printf("%d\n", A);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You have chosen the AND logic gate \n");
        A = 0;
        printf("%d\n", A);
    }
}
```

I am really confused about how I would store an input with more than one character. Such as "AND" or something.

My code just doesn't seem to enter any of the IF statements, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `C`?  For the `%s` specifier, you need an array of `char`, not the address of a single `char`.  Also, `'AND'` is probably not what you think -- it's not a string, but an `int`.  You'd normally only use single quotes with *one* character inside (to get the value of that character as an `int`).  Use double quotes for a string literal, and compare with `strcmp()` or similar.

Comment: The line `(A && B == 1);` does nothing, please observe compiler warnings.

Comment: I guess that `scanf("%s", &C);` should be `scanf("%s", C);` but you have not posted sufficient code. I think your main problem is not logic gates, but basic C syntax.

Answer (score 2):

1. First use a character array to read the type of the logic gate `char str[10]; scanf("%s", str)`
2. Then compare the string as such `if (!strcmp(str, "AND")) { // matched }`

Answer (score 0):

Does your code even compiles?
Show your variable declarations for A, B and C.

```
printf("Thank you, now please enter the logic gate");
scanf("%s", &C);
if (C == 'AND') 
// '' means char, you most likely want string here
// so you need to use strncmp() to compare strings

if (A == 1 && B == 1)
{
    (A && B == 1);
    // ^ This is not a valid syntax for comparing values
```